# What makes "Oh Hanukkah" sound Jewish?

Tags: scales, analysis, genre

Recently, I've been studying the effect of scale choice on the mood and feel of music. Songs using the major scale tend to sound happy. Songs using the minor scale tend to sound sad. Songs using less common scales tend to have a unique and sometimes culturally specific feel to them.

"Oh Hanukkah" seems to be a quintessentially Jewish song, and not just because of the words. You hear the melody and you think "That's Jewish all right." That being the case, I would have guessed that it used a scale that's common and somewhat specific to Jewish music, such as the Phrygian dominant scale (also known as the "Jewish scale"). But surprisingly, it uses the ordinary natural minor scale.

So if it's not the choice of scale, then what is it that makes "Oh Hanukkah" sound Jewish? I know that this is a somewhat subjective question, but there's got to be some feature of the song that creates our impression of it belonging to this cultural style. Could it be something about the rhythm or the particular progression of notes? Thank you.

P.S. Out of curiosity, I created an altered version of the song that uses the Phrygian dominant scale instead of the natural minor scale. You can check it out [here](https://flat.io/score/627ed5c96eba610012a63f70-oh-hanukkah-in-e-phrygian-dominant?sharingKey=62d63aad8a548b041c64d4c5becd9b8005760c03c746657ddf3105389848d6b2951ad9a8201d26986223a0a08f8f27f00a4e5f9aac0e6f4a1eb3b595f08aadb7).

Comment: Your PS is firmly off topic and I think you should edit out the request for feedback and instead ask for feedback in chat

Comment: Agreed. The latter portion of the post should be moved to chat. It's not uncommon for posted music to receive feedback there. (cc: @ToddWilcox)

Comment: I'm so sorry about that. I have removed the request for feedback. Is that okay, or should I remove the rest of the P.S. as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important element is the obviously upbeat nature of the song. It's clearly celebratory, yet in minor. This is a common characteristic in Jewish music.

Another aspect is the rhythm: a sequence of eighth notes followed by emphasized quarter notes on beats three and four. This is another "Jewish sounding" element.

A couple of examples:

**Hinei Ma Tov**

The song is about the joys of community, is in minor, and has a  characteristic rhythm comprising two beats of triplets followed by two quarter notes.

[Hinei Ma Tov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehnKHhJ26pQ) (YouTube)

**Hava Nagila**

The quintessential Jewish celebratory song, is in a minor-sounding mode, and features a "reverse" of the previously described rhythm: starting with two strong beats, then three eighth notes.

[Hava Nagila](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSTOcyevIOE) (YouTube)

---

Much of what we associate as "Jewish" music is probably better described as "Eastern European" music, as much of the former comes from the latter and shares elements of meter, rhythm, melody, and mode. Raucous minor-mode music is common — I often hear it as Russian, Polish, Hungarian, ....